# 3d Implicit Trigonometry help?

Tags: trigonometry, multivariable-calculus, graphing-functions, 3d, implicit-differentiation

I'm trying to understand implicit 3D trigonometry, specifically with this equation:

$$\sin(y)+\cos(z)=\cos(x)$$

Can someone please explain to me what is going on with this equation? I really can't see how it was formed at all. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any precise questions regarding this equation?

Comment: Not really any precise questions, I'm not looking for something specific, just a basic explanation of the calculus involved.

Comment: No calculus: it's just a fact that for three points $\,x,y,z\,$ , the equation given holds...without further data it could be hard to say anything more.